# Git: expire ssh keys just like passwords expire?

Tags: security, git, ssh-keys

I'm setting up git in a corporate environment. Git operations will be primarily though SSH using a single account with SSH keys used for access control. (http will be used for account configuration, web-based code browsing but little else.)

But the idea of having SSH keys that never expire sounds foolish to me. **It would just take one compromised desktop to leak a private key and an intruder would have access to our intellectual property in perpetuity.**

I've done a lot of googling and there is very little information about this. Which alarms me because I don't think I'm on the wrong track.

It would be easy enough to expire keys on a regular basis, although tools like GitLab and Stash don't make it simple. We have a "`git login`" wrapper script for sending SSH public keys to the server. It can ensure that old keys are not just re-used and it can also make sure to use special keys (as specified in`~/.ssh/config` ) so that we are not regularly overwriting somebody's `~/.ssh/id_da*` and stopping their other logins.
    (Although using keys in a non-default location specified in a ssh `config` file might be problematic for some of my lon-linux (Windows) users.)

Has anybody else done this? What is industry best practice?

**Update**

Ok, so it looks like part of the answer is "This is exactly what SSH passphrases are meant for." So the remaining questions are along the lines of

*Is there a way to enforce use of and regular changing of passphrases? I'm assuming people will comply, it just needs to be easy for them.*

And, having said that, ssh passphrases eliminate the ability of doing git operations in a cron job. Which would be a real hindrance not to be able to do.

Comment: Have you considered adding some sort of multi-factor authentication?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14983/how-often-should-an-ssh-key-pair-be-changed. However I'm with EEAA use a second factor auth, personally I like duo from DuoSecurity

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I'm in DevOps --a team of four of us-- not in a large IT department. We try to be lean and mean provide more service than big centralized IT while being much much less intrusive. Implementing a two-factor authentication scheme is simply not on our radar at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no, there is no way within ssh to enforce regular changing pass phrases.

As you're using a single account presumably all the public keys will be in a single authorised_keys file so you could invalidate keys by removing them from it. This though feels like too much effort and people could just use the same pass phrase on a different key.

A way to ease your problem is to use multi-factor authentication, this way, even if the key/pass phrase is compromised there is another layer in the way.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the claim "It would just take one compromised desktop to leak a private key and an intruder would have access to our intellectual property in perpetuity." Remove the key from authorized_keys. Done. I was going to suggest `RevokedKeys` in sshd_config but that isn't needed.

Comment: I guess that if someone has compromised a key and you don't have a method of forcing a change then the intruder has access to the data while the key is valid. Multi-factor auth does solve that issue.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I'm in DevOps --a team of four of us-- not in a large IT department. We try to be lean and mean provide more service than big centralized IT while being much much less intrusive. Implementing a two-factor authentication scheme is simply not on our radar at the moment.

Yes, we can revoke keys and/or force users to re-send their keys or force users to run a login script that gives them a new passphrase. I just wonder what the industry standard is on these things.

Comment: @Mort if you all have smart phones duo will only take a couple of hours to install and for small orgs it's $1/user/month or free for less than 10 users if personal use.

Comment: We're not small. We're big, and across countries.

Comment: // , I think ssh.org has a solution for this